# what is the difference between $("#my-modal").modal('toggle') and $("#my-modal").modal('show') in bootstrap jquery modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show my modal on click of button.
 But using `$("#my-modal").modal('toggle')` and  `$("#my-modal").modal('show')` show same result what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

"[Toggle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/toggle)," in this sense, means to switch between states. As [the documentation says](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#modaltoggle), `toggle` *toggles* the modal (opens it if it's closed, closes it if it's open). [`show`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#modalshow) *shows* the modal (doesn't do anything if it's already open).